# adding textfield over movieclip images

Tags: textfield, movieclip, visible

I have several images, which are Symbols (movieClip) with Alpha parameter.
And i'm creating dynamic textfield from AS3 to be able change text every few seconds.

Problem is that everything worked good till i converted images to MovieClips. But after that my textfields are not visible.

Here is the code:

```
textFormat = new TextFormat();
textfield = new TextField();

textFormat.font = new customFonts().fontName;
textFormat.size = 16;
textFormat.align = "center";
textFormat.color = 0xFFFFFF;

textfield.defaultTextFormat = textFormat;
textfield.embedFonts = true;
textfield.width = 480;
textfield.height = 95;
textfield.x = 185;
textfield.y = 22;
textfield.wordWrap = true;


addChild (textfield);
```

So the question is - how to bring this textfield to the top so it would be visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding your Text field after the movie clips are being initiated. Think of it as a layer, the text field is at the bottom layer, hence they will not be seen.

I would look at the container class

> The Container class is an abstract base class for components that controls the layout characteristics of child components. You do not create an instance of Container in an application. Instead, you create an instance of one of Container's subclasses, such as Canvas or HBox.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/Container.html

You should be able to change what is displayed.

EDIT:

> Anytime you add a clip it is added on top by default.

You should also look into Z-Index.

If you are coding with Flash Develop then it can get tricky, whilst using Flash Adobe CC can make your life so much easier!

Sorry if it's not that much of an answer.